# Managing Music(Song) Queue using Android Media Framework

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

How to manage song queue(add song, remove song and rearrange) in offline media player application. Is it possible to manage queue using methods provided by 'MediaSessionCompat' such as
`mediasession.addqueue() mediasession.addQueueItem()`  etc.
or we have to manage queue using our own logic.

Comment: as far as I know you have to use your own logic and the player of your choice. Queue is just a helper to manage the objects to be played

Comment: "Queue is just a helper to manage the objects to be played" didn't understand this.  Also there are all methods to maintain queue such as addqueueItem(),removequeueItem(), that's why I am confused now whether to use it or not and what is the use of them. @pantos27

Comment: @AkashBisariya Have u got any solution?

Comment: @SumitShukla No, I have written my own logic.

Comment: Can you some code snippet here or at github?

Comment: You can check my github repositories link given in my profile @SumitShukla